# Form does not submit when clicked due to modernizr being loaded

Tags: javascript, html, forms, modernizr, zurb-foundation

I have a webpage which allows you to change the values of users on it. For some reason, probably obvious but I am overlooking, I am not able to click the submit button (and have it do anything). Here is what I have, there are about five users on the page at once, but previous to this all form tags are closed. From what I can tell it is all valid html, but alas, I may be mistaken.

```
<tr>
    <form name="form2" id="form2" action="updateusers.php" method="post">
        <td><input type="hidden" name="username" value="jett"/>jett</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="jett" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="jel" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="reseller" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="resellerCut" value="0.0000" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dealpercent" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="purchases" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sales" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="nice small radius blue button"/></td>
        <td><a href="deleteuser.php?uid=2" class="small red radius button" style="float:right; color:#fff; padding:0.3em">X</a></td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

EDIT: I have done further debugging. It seems the issue is not with my markup, although as  bažmegakapa my markup is off. What seems to be triggering it is the loading of modernizr.foundation.js. This was skewing my tests. I do not understand however why this would happen on only this page, and modernizr is used throughout the site with no issues. I have reduced a test page down to just the form, table, and modernizr and it stops the clicks from happening. Here is a jsfiddle showing this perplexing behavior http://jsfiddle.net/rg8y3/

Modernizr is not especially used on this page so it will be quite easy for me to remove it. However, the fact that it would break this form specifically and not others, with no warnings nor errors thrown is quite odd.

Comment: You are mistaken. In a `tr` element you can only use `td` or `th` - `form` element is not allowed. I'm not sure whether it should trigger this problem or not - but I'd start with that. If you are unsure whether a snippet is valid or not, you could use the W3C Validator.

Comment: working on my local. Are you not able to catch values?

Comment: @bažmegakapa Thank you. If you look above at the jsfiddle I have posted it seems that the issue is not arising from markup. I will alter my page however to become compliant.

Comment: @amitchhajer  When the script is removed it works normally, yes.

Comment: @jett Then, what does this script do and why do you use it? Don't you have an unminified, uncluttered version with meaningful variable and function names?

Comment: @bažmegakapa it is used for safe degrading features with css & html. It is used by the foundation2 framework by zurb for cross platform and backwords compatibility. This page specifically will only be used by a few people so it is not a big deal if that script is unable to work.

in process of finding one, it came prepackaged with foundation 2 and says custom build.. so hopefully I can find dev file.

Comment: @jett I fail to see how would an unmodified Modernizr prevent your forms submitting, but I have no more time to spend on that minified code, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the modernizr script that appears to break the form submission is related to the touch event detection: this part is quite different from the current version.

When I try the jsfiddle with version 2.5.2 from source, the page fails to submit.

Building the current version of modernizr (with same options at http://modernizr.com/download/#-touch-mq-cssclasses-addtest-teststyles-prefixes-ie8compat-load) and including that script works.

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/jussinen/rg8y3/1/ :If you can update the modernizr script, then you don't need to remove it or make any changes to your page.

However, having said that, if you fix the broken markup as bažmegakapa pointed out, then the script works fine with the Modernizr script you've already got: check http://jsfiddle.net/jussinen/rg8y3/2/ .